# How to create a dialog box in a non-UI thread in a different class?

Tags: android, multithreading, dialog

I'm developing a very simple game in android(that runs in a non-UI thread), I want to make that, when the game is over, it shows a custom dialog box with the score, but the class isn't in the MainActivity class. I can't figure out how to create the dialog in the thread whitout getting any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many ways to do that. One way is to pass your **context** to the class constructor of the game to be able to access the UI through it.

```
public class MyGame {
   private Context context;
   private Handler handler;

   public MyClass(Context context) {
      this.context = context;
      handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
   }
   ...
}
```

and when initializing from activity

```
MyGame game = new MyGame(this);
```

and to show the dialog in your game class, just use this code

```
handler.post(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      // Instanitiate your dialog here
      showMyDialog();
   }
});
```

and this how to show a simple AlertDialog.

```
private void showMyDialog() {
  new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    .setTitle("Som title")
    .setMessage("Are you sure?")
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // continue with delete
        }
     })
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // do nothing
        }
     })
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
    .show();
}
```

Comment: It's all ok until I use the handler to execute the "showMyDialog" method on the game thread. It says me "unreachable statement".

Comment: I've already solved it, i've put that after a infinite while cycle(it was set to true). Now i have any problem, thanks!

Comment: If this is the solution to your problem, mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go back to the UI thread to show the dialog, but you will need a reference to the current Activity (MainActivity I assume) to access to the UI thread and to use as a Context of the dialog. Check the method [runOnUiThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable))

Comment: How do i make that reference?